# Does std::map auto-resize when too many elements are inserted?

Tags: c++, dictionary, resize

Does the STL's std::map auto-resize when too many elements are inserted?  If so, what's the rate?

As I understand, it should have one, but I can't find anything for resize().

If std::map does resize, how can one adjust the resize rate?

Comment: A map isn't like a vector, it is a tree, not a contiguous block of memory.

Answer (score 12):

Maps grow a node at a time as elements are added... you can't "resize" them like a `vector` - grabbing a contiguous chunk of memory earlier instead of many small chunks later - because they don't use contiguous chunks like that anyway.  They have pointers linking individual nodes, with one element per node.

Answer (score 2):

All STL containers automatically "resize" when you insert elements. I.e. when you use `some_container::insert` functionality to insert elements into a container, you don't have to do anyhting else, regardless of how many elements you insert (until you reach some physical limit, like run out of memory or hit `container::max_size()`).

You also meantion "adjusting resize rate"... It is not possible to adjust "resize rate" even in those contanters to which this concept is applicable (like in case of `std::vector`). And `resize` method (even when it exists) does not adjust "resize rate". A container's growth strategy is an implementation detail, not exposed to the user and not controllable by the user.

Meanwhile, a typical implementation of `std::map` will allocate storage for each map element individually. Such container does not have and does not need any "resize rate". Its resize strategy is fixed as "add one more element every time one more element is needed" or "add N more elements every N one more elements are needed".

Comment: `std::array` doesn't automatically resize.

Comment: And I don't think this addresses what the OP is asking for at all.  Obviously he is talking about resizing the backing memory store.  I don't see how this is at all helpful, nor does it explain how a `map` is (may be) implemented.

Comment: @Jamal: Well, `std::array` does not allow you to insert elements either.

Comment: @Ed S.: It is not clear to anyone yet what the OP's primary issue is. Quite the opposite, it might be the fact that the OP errouneously believes that inserting elements into a contaner somehow requires preliminary "resizing" of that container. Or it might be the OP's belief that the "resize rate" is somehow controllable. In that case my answer actyally addresses exactly what the OP is talking about. And it is definitely too early for exaplaining how `map` is implemented.

Comment: Well, adding to a vector can cause an allocation and copy (i.e., "resize").  Also, you can control "resize rate" for a vector in a way if you know the minimum number of elements you will need to store.  I think you're being pedantic.  I understand what the OP is after, and so does @Tony D.

Comment: @Ed S.: No, you are trying to play along with OP's potential (albeit not yet proven) misuse of the term. Inserting an element into a vector *always* causes "resize", since the vector size always grows by one. "Allocation and copy" is not referred to as a "resize", since it can only lead to unnecessary confusion. In order to properly use a vector, one has to understand the difference between size and capacity very cearly.

Comment: As for "understandinmg what the OP is after"... Congratulations, but this is not exactly useful in a sutuation when the OP does not seem to cleary understand they are after. The idea is to help the OP to develop that understanding, instead of playing along with their misconceptions.

Comment: Ok, fine; if you don't know what the OP is asking for, why did you post an answer at all? And please stop playing around like you don't understand that the OP is referring to the backing store here, not the logical size of the container.  Of course it grows by one element *logically* when you add an element, no one with half a brain would question that.

Comment: +1 For whatever it's worth, I think this answer adds useful context - no particular point in modifying it to redundantly cover what I have, any more than for me to flesh out these perspectives - it's all good.  Regarding "not possible to adjust resize rate even in those containers to which this concept is applicable" - an exception is [unordered_map::max_load_factor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/max_load_factor).